# MUI TreeView -> TreeItem change background color only on select item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can someone help to figure out how not to change `TreeItem` background color when I expand node and change it only if node selected. Here is my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/filesystemnavigator-material-demo-forked-1kwcoc?file=/demo.js

Comment: Just a curious question. If we want to expand an element, we need to click which means we are selecting that element. If you select the `TreeItem` elements, the tree element background is not coming. Isn't that you are expecting?

Comment: @mchowdam When I click on "expand icon", I want only to expand node without changing focus (changing background). And focus only when clicking item itself (to the right of the expand icon). Like here: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3165635/89707096-7ff96400-d96b-11ea-9254-edecda9dca46.gif